# How to get the value from a web api response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a ASP.NET web application where I have a controller with an action that receives table vale and returns JSON for the client side grid binding. In this action I want to make a call to a WEB API, receive the response as JSON and use the JSON string to bind gridview.

(And I'm  allowed to call the WEB API directly with JavaScript)

I manage to make the request to the Web API but I can't figure out how to read out the JSON string.

Here is my method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function codeAddress() {

       var Drop = 'api/Task/dis';
       debugger;

       $.ajax({
           url: Drop,
           type: 'GET',
           data: JSON.stringify({}),
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",                                    
                success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                alert(data);
                $('#gvbooksdetails tr:not(:first)').remove();
                    $('#gvbooksdetails').append("<tr><th>AuthorName</th><th>Bookname </th><th>Booktype</th><th>Publisher</th></tr>")
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                   $('#gvbooksdetails').append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].AuthorName + "</td><td>" + data.d[i].BooName + "</td></tr>" + data.d[i].BookType + "</td></tr>" + data.d[i].Publication + "</td></tr>")
                };
           },
           error: function () {
               alert("Error");
           }
       });
       return false;
    }
```

Below is the  controller code:

```
 <Route("api/Task/dis")> _
    <AcceptVerbs("GET", "PUT", "POST")>
    Public Function dis() As IHttpActionResult

        Dim gsgrid = (From d2 In db1.demodisplay(0).AsQueryable() Select d2).CopyToDataTable

        If gsgrid Is Nothing Then
            Return NotFound()
        End If

        Return Ok(gsgrid)

    End Function
```

I am getting the values in gsgrid...but in the JavaScript in that alert I am getting object;object like this.
How to assign the data sources to bind grid view?

Comment: jquery is parsing the JSON. if you need it as a string use `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @DanielA.White I have already used JSON.stringify.. but I am getting object object  in the data ...Actually we use to assign gsgrid in server side as gvbooksdetails.datasource = gsgrid .But in client side how to  assign It

Comment: i'm not sure what the problem is. the JSON is already read and made into an object - `data`.

Comment: @DanielA.White will you use web api for Get method and assigning for grid view ..provide me any references..

Comment: success: function (data)  { alret( data.d[i].AuthorName)} Its working fine..